# Remove all sentences where number to character ratio is greater than the average in the text

Tags: r, regex, text, substring, text-mining

Is it possible to find and delete all sentences containing a higher number to character ratio?
I created the following function to calculate the ratio in a given string:

```
a <- "1aaaaaa2bbbbbbb3"

Num_Char_Ration <- function(string){
length(unlist(regmatches(string,gregexpr("[[:digit:]]",string))))/nchar(as.character(string))
}
Num_Char_Ration(a)
#0.1875
```

The task is now to find a method to calculate the ratio for a sentence(so for a character sequence between ending with a ".") and then to delete sentences with a higher ratio from the text. For example:

```
input:
a <- " aa111111. bbbbbb22. cccccc3." 
output:
#"bbbbbb22. cccccc3."
```

Comment: By a higher ratio do you mean the maximum?

Comment: Yes, for example. Or all sentences having a higher ratio that the average ratio in all sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `stringr` package to count digits and characters:

```
# Original data
input <- " aa111111. bbbbbb22. cccccc3." 
# Split by . 
inputSplit <- strsplit(input, "\\.")[[1]]

# Count digits and all alnum in splitted string
counts <- sapply(inputSplit, stringr::str_count, c("[[:digit:]]", "[[:alnum:]]"))

# Get ratios and collapse text back
paste(inputSplit[counts[1, ] / counts[2, ] < 0.5], collapse = ".")
# [1] " bbbbbb22. cccccc3"
```

`counts` looks like this:

```
# To get ratio between digits and string
# Divide first row by second row
      aa111111  bbbbbb22  cccccc3
[1,]         6         2        1
[2,]         8         8        7
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple base solution:

```
x <- strsplit(input,"\\.")[[1]]
x <- x[nchar(x) < 2 * nchar(gsub("\\d","",x))]
paste(x,collapse=".")
# [1] " bbbbbb22. cccccc3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split up your long string into single words! (`strsplit()` for eg)

data:

```
words <- c("aa111111.","bbbbbb22.","cccccc3.")
```

code:

```
library(magrittr)
fun1 <- function(x) {
    num <- gsub("\\D","",x) %>% nchar
    char<- gsub("[^A-z]","",x,perl=T) %>% nchar

    if(num <= char) return(x) else NULL
}

sapply(words,fun1) %>% unlist %>% unname
```

result:

```
#[1] "bbbbbb22." "cccccc3."
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Simplified num to char ratio function
Num_Char_Ration <- function(string) {
  lengths(regmatches(x, gregexpr("[0-9]", x))) / nchar(x)
}

clear_nmbstring <- function(x) {
  x <- strsplit(x, ".", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
  cleanx <- trimws(x)
  x <- x[Num_Char_Ration(cleanx) < 0.5]
  paste(x, collapse = ".")
}

# Example:
string <- c(" aa111111. bbbbbb22. cccccc3.")
clear_nmbstring(string)
[1] " bbbbbb22. cccccc3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it in base R. Adapted Andre's code.

```
my_string <- " aa111111. bbbbbb22. cccccc3." 

#Split paragraph into sentences based on '.'
my_string <- unlist(strsplit(my_string, '(?<=\\.)\\s+', perl=TRUE))
#Removing sentences with more numbers than letters
my_string <- subset(my_string,nchar(gsub("\\D","",my_string)) <= nchar(gsub("[^A-z]","",my_string,perl=T)))

my_string
##[1] "bbbbbb22." "cccccc3."
```

If you then want to combine these sentences back into a paragraph, you can use

```
paste(my_string,collapse=" ")
##[1] "bbbbbb22. cccccc3."
```